# How do I force a new module to inherit the file permissions the modules directory has, after update?

Tags: drush

I'm using Drush 7 on Windows Server 2012 and IIS 8. Whenever I use `drush up` to update a third-party module, IIS can't access the files because during the update process, when drush is replacing the module files, the entire module folder contains permissions assigned to **only** the administrator, with **inheritance disabled**.

I need Drush to replace the module files with **inheritance enabled**; otherwise, Drupal will complain that it can't read the module files and break my site.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What "inheritance" are we talking about here?

Comment: Inheritance in the sense that the new module files should inherit the permissions of the parent folder (i.e. the 'sites/all/modules' folder).

Comment: Oh right, so file system permissions? Was there something about Drupal you needed to know?

Comment: Well specifically, how to either make drush conform to the file system permissions defined by the module folder or whether there's some sort of permissions option I've missed when setting up Drupal on my server that's causing this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but recently I stumble upon the same problem:

- Site installed on IIS 8 under Windows Server 2012 R2
- After updating with Drush core and modules, permissions of modules
  and updated files get messed up.

Solution I found is:

- right click on website folder> Security > Advanced
- check: *"Replace all child object permission entries with inheritable
  permission entries from this object"*
- Apply

If files don't shows navigate to `/sites/default/files` or whenever files are stored and change permission to this folder and subfolders.

[image]